# Show that the function is increasing

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $q>1$ and $f(h)=\dfrac{(1+h)^{q}-1}{h}$ for $h>0$.
How can I show that the function $f$ is increasing on $(0,\infty)$?
The problem I come across is showing that the derivative $f^{\prime}(h)=\dfrac{1+qh(1+h)^{q-1}-(1+h)^{q}}{h^{2}}$ is positive.

Comment: I have a verbal proof, but I want to see a computational one. Here is my proof: Consider $\frac{(1+h)-1}{h}$ (increasing/increasing), which results a nondecreasing function (precisely, constant), if we (strictly) increase the power of $(1+h)$ (to $q$), we will get a faster function in the numerator, which will give us a strictly increasing function.

Comment: What was your difficulty in showing $g(h)>r(h)$ from the steps I gave?  If $g(0)=r(0)$, and $g$ increases faster than $r$, we are done.

Comment: @Michael No dificulty in it. Defining $\nu(h):=\frac{g(h)}{r(h)}$, we have $\nu^{\prime}(h)=q\frac{(1+h)^{q}-(1+h)}{(1+h)^{q+2}}>0$ for all $h\geq0$, which justifies what you have said. I was actually looking for some kind of a binomial expansion (or Taylor's series) involving proof.

Comment: That will also work, noting that $v(0)=1$.  =) The first thing I thought of when looking at the problem was a binomial expansion, which is the most natural, but that only seems to work when $q$ is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

As a hint, you can define:
$g(h) = 1 + qh(1+h)^{q-1}$.
$r(h) = (1+h)^q$

Then you can show $g(0)=r(0)=1$ and $g'(h) > r'(h)$ for all $h > 0$.

So $\int_0^t g'(h)dh > \int_0^t r'(h)dh$ for all $t>0$.

Comment: The point here is of course to show $g(h)>r(h)$ for all $h>0$, which is equivalent to $f'(h)>0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** use the convexity of $x\to x^q$ and the fact that 
$$
x \to \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y}
$$is non decreasing in $x$ when $f$ is convex.